# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this3.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Problem with stack navigation between the screens.
I am displaying data on my 'SveKategorije' screen.
It's basically categories buttons, when i click on button i just want to show another screen for now, but it is not working for some reason.
When i put onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('screenname')}
it gives me this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQU4d.png)
I am using (react-native - 0.57.7)

Here is router.js code  (where i declare my routes)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';

//TABS
import Categories from '../tabs/categories';
import Home from '../tabs/home';
import Me from '../tabs/me';

//screens for CATEGORIES 
import ViceviPoKategoriji from '../components/Ispis/ViceviPoKategoriji';


//CATEGORIES STACK 
export const categoriesFeedStack = createStackNavigator({

    SveKategorije: {
        screen: Categories,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'KATEGORIJE',
        },
    },

    ViceviPoKategoriji: {
        screen: ViceviPoKategoriji,
    }

});


//TABS
export const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({


    Categories: {
        screen: categoriesFeedStack,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Kategorije',
            label: 'Kategorije',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="list" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
        }

    },
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Pocetna',
            label: 'Kategorije',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="home" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
        }

    },
    Me: {
        screen: Me,
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Profil',
            label: 'Kategorije',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="account-circle" size={35} color={tintColor} />,
        }
    },

},
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        showIcon: true
    },

);
```

Here is 'SveKategorije' screen

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, StackNavigator, navigate } from 'react-navigation';


export default class SveKategorije extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: null
        }
    }




    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('http://centarsmijeha.com/api/allCategories')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.data,
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
    render() {

        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            let data = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {

                return (
                    <View key={key} style={styles.item}>

                        <Button
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ViceviPoKategoriji')}
                            title={val.categoryName}
                        />
                    </View>
                );

            });
            return (
                <ScrollView>

                    {data}
                </ScrollView >
            );
        }
    }
}




//CSS
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        width: '100%'
    },
    item: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        width: '100%',
        textAlign: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

and here is 'ViceviPoKategoriji' screen ( the screen that should be displayed on click of any buttons from 'SveKategorije' screen )

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView } from 'react-native';


export default class ViceviPoKategoriji extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: null,
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch('http://centarsmijeha.com/api/jokesByCategory/16')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseJson.data,
                })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            });
    }
    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
        } else {
            let data = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {

                return <View key={key} style={styles.item}><Text>{val.jokeText}</Text></View>

            });
            return (
                <ScrollView>

                    {data}
                </ScrollView >
            );
        }
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    item: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        marginTop: 50,
        marginRight: '15%',
        marginLeft: '15%',
        width: '70%',
        textAlign: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#eee'
    }
});
```

Comment: SveKategorije does not exist in your router stack therefore as far as the navigation library goes, this screen does not exist, that's why when you're trying to use this.props.navigation you get that it's undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-navigation is props based navigation.
I think your component don't have navigation props.
Please check whether your component have navigation props.

do

```
render() {
  console.log(this.props.navigation)
  // or debugger
  return (
```

If result of console.log is undefined, then add 'import SveKategorije' to your routing file.

Comment: Imported 'SveKategorije' and putted it in as screen, worked for me<3

Answer (score 0):

You have to do few more setups for navigating from the component.You can get access to a navigator through a ref and pass it to the NavigationService which we will later use to navigate.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case I accidentally used this.props.navigation inside functional component. If any one made a mistake like this, will check u r code once again.