# TypeError : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this3.props')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-props

Im trying to use react-navigation in my RN app with expo. But when I trying to pass << 
 this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail"); >> to my TouchableOpacity onPress, it got me error like this.

> TypeError : undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this3.props')

Under is my code (under whole code is inside of for statement, 'count' is variable used in for statement)

```
lecture_name = lecture_name.slice(1, lecture_name.lastIndexOf('('))
const lecture_value = Value_list[count].slice(4)
all_TO.push(
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.button} key={lecture_value}
            onPress={
              () => {
                // test_to_educlass(lecture_value);
                // test_toRender();
                this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail");
              }
            }
          >
            <Text> {lecture_name} </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          )
```

After some search, I found that I can't access to 'this.props' in function , but I didn't find any answer for my code.

Any one can help me please?

Comment: Can you post the complete code of the component? and also can you log `console.log(this.props)` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Full code is too long and complex to post because Im new to RN.
And I already checked `console.log(this.props)` return perfectly

Comment: And also `console.log(this.props.navigation)` returns perfectly? If yes, I think there's some mistake in the `StackNavigator`.

Comment: Yes it returns perfectly too. I thinks error comes because I use `this.props.navigation.navigate` in for statement (function). Isn't is? 
I checked my `StackNavigator` once again, but I didn't find anything strange.

Comment: I found [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54543175/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this3-props-navigation-navigate] this. Its pretty similar with my problem and code too. But I can't solve my error with that answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: In your original code before importing `useNavigation` can you create a new `onPress` function as a callback like this and add a `this` binding in your constructor too.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }

 onPress() {
  this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail");
  }

<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.button}
  key={lecture_value}
  onPress={() => this.onPress()}
>
  <Text> {lecture_name} </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>;
```

Comment: I fixed my code as you said but It gaves me another error `TypeError:(0, _native.useNavigation) is not a function. ~ undefined`.

Comment: Yeah it gaves me same error :( (same error as first I posted)

Comment: I have updated the code again. Can you check it out?